# Subgroups of $S_{n}$ of index $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

We know that for $n\geq{5}$ any subgroup of $S_{n}$ of index $n$ is isomorphic to $S_{n-1}$. We know that by looking at the set of functions that fix a given $j$, we can obtain $n$ such subgroups lying inside of $S_{n}$. Are there any more subgroups of index $n$, or do these characterize all subgroups of $S_{n}$ of index $n$?

Comment: There are $12$ other subgroups of index $6$, all isomorphic to $S_5$, when $n=6$. Otherwise there are only $n$ such subgroups. This is essentially equivalent to the fact that there are no outer automorphisms of $S_n$ when $n \ne 6$, which has been discussed many times before.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thank you.

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you guide me through the equivalence or point me to a place where this is discussed in some detail?

Comment: For any $H < S_n$ with $|S_n:H|=n$, the action of $S_n$ by multiplication on the left cosets of $H$ gives a homomorphism $\phi:S_n \to S_n$ in which the image is a transitive subgroup, and hence has order divisible by $n$. Now we need to use the fact that the only normal subgroups of $S_n$ for $n \ge 5$ are $1, A_n$ and $S_n$ to conclude that $\ker \phi = 1$ and hence $\phi$ is an automorphism. (This is also true ofr $n=3,4$.)

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks again.